# Insert and echo with jQuery (AJAX?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

On my website, multiple users will be completing a form simultaneously, and I want all these people to be able to see what radiobox the other one checks before submitting the form.

Like in real time, so that if me and a friend does this test at the same time, as soon as he clicks (a delay won't matter) say "Awesome", I wanna be able to echo that out in a table.

```
<form>
    <input type='radio' value='Awesome'>
    <input type='radio' value='Awful'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<table>
    <th>
        <tr>User</tr>
        <tr>Question 1</tr>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $userid; ?>
        <td><?php echo $answer1; ?>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

I kinda think that I need get.JSON here and/or AJAX, but I'm not sure how to do it.. There will be multiple questions to the form, all displayed on the same page. I need to send it to a table in the database temporarily with get.JSON and have another script do echo it out continously?

Any suggestions or ideas or code snippets that might help me on my way would be much appreciated.

Mo

Comment: Ok, this is going to be straight up complicated, no matter what. The page will have to do an AJAX post back to the server every time someone clicks a button (storing it into a database!) *and* the page will have to constantly check the server to see if anyone did anything, and if so, reflect those changes (think about how Stack Overflow shows you little notifications when someone answers a question or leaves a comment: that kind of system). You're probably better of getting help if you split this question up for each of the tasks involved, and I recommend making an attempt at each before that.

Comment: The easiest way would be to look into something with push capabilities, like websockets. Else you'll have to poll your server every few seconds.

Comment: @Shilly Ah yes, websockets.  I forget things such as that exist, on account of never having written an application that needs push notifications.

Comment: I'd definitely go for websockets on this one. Short polling (like Ajax) will eat up so many server resources, you'll already start noticing long load times on 10/15 users at the same time. There's only so many requests per second your mysql server can handle. Even a full dedicated mysql server can only handle about 250 / sec. A websocket on the other hand will use about 5% on 1000 requests per sec (tested this myself).

Comment: So.. Something ugly like a javascript file which updates a php file every few seconds and returns it in a div one the page is a better solutions for a beginner? That, I have done before and it's not exactly nice.. I'm kinda cool with php really, it's just JavaScript(jQuery) that's a tad bit confusing sometimes.

Comment: The main issue is the polling technique. Even without the use of a database server, you're talking about a lot of requests per second to the server. There's no "easy" way to do this. Whether you'll use Ajax or Websockets, it's going to be complicated. Might as well do it the right way from the start.

Comment: However, the downside to websockets is that you'll need root access to your server. If you hired some cheap VPS, you won't have this and therefor can't fire up the socket server. Ajax will be your only choice. Though it's not viable at all because a VPS will be way to slow to handle it.